# Primitive wrappers in Python for Protobuf

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I'm using proto3 and have a message in some `.proto` file defined as:

```
message Response {
  google.protobuf.BoolValue field = 1;
  ...
}
```

In order to initialize `Response` in Python, I need to create a boolean primitive wrapper and attach some value.

If I were to initialize this value to `True`, this is fine. From a Python notebook:

```
In [52]: from google.protobuf import wrappers_pb2 as wrappers
         boo = wrappers.BoolValue(value=True)
         boo

Out [52]: value: true
```

If I were to initialize this value to `False`, no wrapped object is created:

```
In [52]: from google.protobuf import wrappers_pb2 as wrappers
         boo = wrappers.BoolValue(value=False)
         boo

Out [52]:
```

How can create a `BoolValue` initialized to false?

Comment: Are you sure there's something wrong with what you're doing? (If you just use `boo` as you want to, does something fail?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Non-truthy values are removed from the fields list [as implemented here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/python/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py#L662).

```
>> boo = wrappers.BoolValue(value=True)
>> boo.ListFields()
[(<google.protobuf.descriptor.FieldDescriptor object at 0x10a037bd0>, True)]

>> boo = wrappers.BoolValue(value=False)
>> boo.ListFields()
[]
```

In order to access the message value you can write it like this:

```
>> boo = wrappers.BoolValue(value=True)
>> boo.value
True

>> boo = wrappers.BoolValue(value=False)
>> boo.value
False
```